# Asp Net Core URL Rewrite not downloading CSS JS files

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-core, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm working on a solution which has two applications hosted in IIS

1. Application 1: Hosted in port 80/443 and accessible to outside network. This handles all incoming API Requests.
2. Application 2: Hosted in port 33957 and behind firewall (not exposed to outside network).

Both applications are working fine when browsed.

Since Application 1 is exposed to outside network, i have written a rewrite url. When ever, some request are received by this application, it has to rewrite and send it to application 2. Seems like this is happening. However, the static files such as css, js are not displayed in the browser. How can i sort it out?

**Application 1 : Startup config.**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //Other parts of the code removed for clarity//

        //CORS POLICY
        app.UseCors(p => p
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        );

        //REWRITE METHODS
        var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
                        .Add(new PotreeRewriter());

        app.UseRewriter(rewrite);

        //Other parts of the code removed for clarity//
    }
```

**Rewriter:**

Concept is simple. Whenever a url is requested with a particular string included (/895da1e9-a065-40df/), i'm rewriting that to different url running in local host. Since this is rewrite, it happens in server side.

```
public class PotreeRewriter : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        var full_url = $@"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.PathBase}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
        var url = request.Path.ToString();
        string potreeviewer = @"/895da1e9-a065-40df/";
        // Rewrite to index
        if (url.Contains(potreeviewer) && request.Method == "GET")
        {
            request.Host = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HostString("localhost", 39987); //Change host value
            request.PathBase = ""; //Remove base, if any
                                   // rewrite and continue processing
            int end_index = url.IndexOf(potreeviewer);
            string to_replace = url.Substring(0, end_index + potreeviewer.Length);
            string new_url = url.Replace(to_replace, "/acl-i/");
            request.Path = new_url;
            full_url = $@"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.PathBase}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = full_url; //Just to see if it is reaching correct location. Will remove later.
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;

        }
    }
}
```

**Results from browser**

I tried to reach a particular css file using direct url and also using the rewrite method. Below are my results.

**Direct URL**

[image]

**Rewrite URL**

[image]

It can be seen that, in rewrite URL, the content is not received. How do i sort this? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following entry to your web.config file, within the "system.webServer" element:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't return me the files. Where should this be entered? In the web.config file in IIS wwwroot or in the dotnetcore project?

Answer (score 0):

Application 1 and Application 2 are different sites, so they can only exchange data by instantiate new HTTP request (e.g. using HttpClient in Application 1 to call to Application 2). You rewrite url from Application 1 and expect it can get result from Application 2 without sending any request to Application 2, this cannot be done.
Rewriting url can be only proceeded when you're on the same application.